# psycopg2: (col1, col2) IN my_list: ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "ARRAY"

Tags: sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to execute this sql via psyopg2:

```
select indexname from pg_indexes where (tablename, indexname) in ( 
      ('tab1', 'index1'),
      ('tab2', 'index2') 
);
```

Here is the code:

```
cursor.execute(
'select tablename, indexname from pg_indexes where (tablename, indexname) IN %s;', [
    [('tab1', 'col1'), ('tab2', 'col2')],
               ])
```

I get this exception:

```
ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "ARRAY"
LINE 1: ...e from pg_indexes where (tablename, indexname) IN ARRAY[('ta...
```

How to pass a list of tuples to PostgreSQL vis psyopg2?

Answer (score 23):

If you pass a tuple instead a list, it works:

```
cursor.execute(
'select tablename, indexname from pg_indexes where (tablename, indexname) IN %s;', [
    tuple([('tab1', 'col1'), ('tab2', 'col2')]),
               ])
```

Don't ask my why it fails if you pass a list.

Comment: A Python list is adapted by Psycopg to a Postgresql array as you saw in the error message. A tuple is adapted to a record.